# Dropbox File MIME type?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dropbox

just recently implemented dropbox file chooser app, but response that I get upon successfully chosen file doesn't include type (MIME type) of file I am linking ?

Anyone had any experience with that ?

I mean, I tried HEAD requesting the given link that Chooser gave me, but I'm not getting any data of it (perhaps dbox disabled it for some reason).

Anyways, any help would be appreciated :)

Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that a `HEAD` request against the actual file should work. (Make sure you have a direct link, not a link to the preview page.)

But I believe Dropbox is just guessing the MIME type based on the file extension, so you could do the same.